# How to back out of mass update in SQL Replication

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

We have a database which is set up in Merge Replication.

We accidentally updated hundreds of thousands of records in a large published table on the publisher database.

We did is something like this:-

```
update LargeTable set Field=Field
```

So basically, every record got updated to be the same - no data was actually changed. However, every record in the table is now being delivered to every subscriber and the whole system has come to a halt. We are very worried this will take days and days to complete.

How can we safely remove data from the msmerge_contents and msmerge_genhistory table? Are there other system replication tables to remove records from? I can see the exact records in these tables that refer to the mass update. I just don't want to remove them without knowing it is safe to do so.